# How to solve SLF4J exception

Tags: java, slf4j

I am using Tess4j API in creating an OCR system. But after I running he program it gives the following message in Apache Tomcat.

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

I have inserted all the required jar files and dll files. But I don't get the text extracted from the provided image. Is this due to the above message? Please help me.Thank you in advance

Comment: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.

Comment: Is it due to this text is not extracted?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned on http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html

> This error is reported when the org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder
>   class could not be loaded into memory. This happens when no
>   appropriate SLF4J binding could be found on the class path. Placing
>   one (and only one) of slf4j-nop.jar, slf4j-simple.jar,
>   slf4j-log4j12.jar, slf4j-jdk14.jar or logback-classic.jar on the class
>   path should solve the problem.

Did you also bind the jar files on your class path?

Comment: I have added logback-classic.jar also. But didnt't combine with class path. How can I combine the jar with class path?

Comment: Open the context menu on the project, and select Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries. From here, you can add JAR files to the build path, whether they are inside your workspace or not.